# Is there a way to install Beagle on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, installation, repository, search

Beagle, a great desktop search engine which was part of Ubuntu is discontinued for some time now and removed from Ubuntu from 10.04 and afterwards. Even though there are a lot of alternative apps such as Tracker and Catfish I would like to continue using Beagle, til it is no longer usable.

So, I was wondering if there is any way at all to install Beagle on Ubuntu 11.04. Whether that is an unstable synaptic package or a .deb file from some shady site on the internet.

Even though my knowledge on Linux is limited, could I browse to a older Ubuntu live cd and extract it (is that even possible?) from the installed repositories as .deb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last release of [Beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_%28software%29) is the 0.3.9. You can download it from Debian [here](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/beagle) (look at the end of the page).